# C++ concatenating macro definitions

Tags: c++, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

In C++ (G++ to be specific), can one concatenate two macro definitions, **without spaces**, to create a 3rd definition?  For example, how to I take

```
#define _LOAD _mm256_load
#define _FLOAT ps
```

and operate on them thusly

```
#define _LOAD_FLOAT   ****do something with _FLOAT and _LOAD here *****
```

to create a definition functionally equivalent to the following:

```
#define _LOAD_FLOAT _mm256_load_ps
```

Comment: `#define _LOAD_FLOAT ##_LOAD##_FLOAT`

Comment: `##` should serve you well.

Comment: The guidelines say not to use macros.. Just sayin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can concatenate macro replacements with the `##` preprocessor directive and some auxiliary quoting macros.

```
#define _LOAD _mm256_load
#define _FLOAT ps

#define CAT(X, Y, Z) X ## Y ## Z
#define CMB(A, B) CAT(A, _, B)

#define FOO CMB(_LOAD, _FLOAT)
```

Now use `FOO`, or just `CMB(_LOAD, _FLOAT)` directly.